# If $e^{2 \pi i f_n(x)}$ converges to $e^{2 \pi i f(x)}$ then $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of smooth functions on $I=[0,1]$ such that $f_n(0)=0$. Now it is given that for given $\varepsilon>0,\ \exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}$  such that$ \|e^{2 \pi i f_n(x)}-e^{2 \pi i f(x)}\|<\varepsilon$ for every $n\ge n_0$, where $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and $  f(0)=0.$  From this how can I conclude that $f_n\to f$.

Comment: You definitely cannot conclude this, because for example, if we set $$f_n(x) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} 0, & x = 0 \\ 1 & x \in (0,1] \end{matrix} \right\}$$ and $f(x) = 0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Then $$e^{2\pi i f_n(x)} = e^{2\pi i f(x)}$$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ but clearly $f_n \not \to f$.

Comment: In what sense is the convergence $e^{2\pi i f_n(x)} \to e^{2\pi i f(x)}$? In other words, what is $\|\cdot\|$?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, I mean the same.

Comment: @UmbertoP. The norm is the usual Euclidean norm.

Comment: @User8128 I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$\|e^{ia}-e^{ib}\|^2=2(1-\cos(a-b))$$

$$=4\sin^2(\frac{a-b}{2})$$

Comment: But this doesn't help too much because $\sin(\frac{a-b}{2})$ can be near zero even when $a$ and $b$ are very far apart from each other

Comment: if for each $\epsilon>0$, we have $|c|<\epsilon$, it means $c=0$.

Comment: Ok, but what we're claiming here is that $\|e^{2\pi i f(x)} - e^{2\pi i f_n(x)}\| < \epsilon$ which shows that $$2 \lvert \sin (\pi (f(x) - f_n(x)) \rvert < \epsilon$$ but this does not mean that $\lvert f(x) - f_n(x)\rvert$ is small necessarily which is what we would like to conclude.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima we want to prove the convergence. As mention by User8128, $2 \lvert \sin (\pi (f(x) - f_n(x)) \rvert < \epsilon$ does not imply given $\varepsilon'>0,\ \exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\ge N$,   $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon'$.